# Zapf Dingbats replaced by Adobe Pi Std

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Why is the font Zapf Dingbats replaced by Adobe Pi Std when the PDF is opened by Adobe Reader ?

[image]

Is the Zapf Dingbats fully included within the PDF when generating with DOMPDF ?

I have some issues when sending my PDF to a third party who can't display checkboxes as they are from Zapf Dingbats font.

Comment: Can you provide a sample pdf that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 0):

ZapfDingbats was not fully embedded in the PDF.  If it was, then you would see (Embedded) next to the font name as shown [Embedded example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhsSN.png)  Or it may show (Embedded Subset) if only a subset of the characters were used in the file.  You should check the program that created the PDF to see if there is an option to fully embed the font.